# Lock slashes in place while typing date in input

Tags: jquery, html, date

Using Symfony2.3.4, PHP5.6.3, Twig, HTML5, jQuery2.2.3 and CSS3.

I need to lock the slashes(or separator in general) in an input tag while the user types in the numbers corresponding to day, month and year. More or less would be, for example for typing 15th of May, 2016:

```
Initial input content: __/__/____  
User types 0  
Current input content: 0_/__/____  
User types 5  
Current input content: 05/__/____  
User types 1  
Current input content: 05/1_/____
User types 5  
Current input content: 05/15/____
User types 2  
Current input content: 05/15/2___
User types 0  
Current input content: 05/15/20__
User types 1  
Current input content: 05/15/201_
User types 6  
Current input content: 05/15/2016
```

Basically the number typed must replace the underscore and when the (invisible) cursor reaches the slash, it should skip 1 space forward.

Any doubts or ideas, please answer.

Thanx

Comment: Google for 'date input masking'

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to do this with HTML5 is to use the new input types. For this one, you'd use "date".

```
<input type="date">
```

Comment: This will actually give the user a fully-featured date picker as well.

Comment: can u tell me what it´s supposed to do or what I´m supposed to do after I set the attr